# R Shiny: Using input parameters to select and display value from data frame

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create a little look up function for some confidence intervals using R Shiny. The basic premise is that someone would enter the numerator and denominator and then the lower and upper limits would display. (I realise there are plenty of easier ways to do this but this is just for an example)

I have a data frame which has a column for numerator (succ), denominator (num) and one each for lower limit (a) and upper limit (b). I think the UI is OK, but I can't figure out how to get the value of a and b displayed where num==num and succ==succ. I am very new at this so apologies if this is a basic question!

My code is below, essentially I want the values to be displayed under their respective upper and lower headings.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
h3("Calculate your uncertainty intervals"),

numericInput("num", label = h4("Number of Tests"), value = 5 , min = 1, max = 10),
numericInput("succ", label = h4("Number of Positive Results"), value = 0, min = 0),

h4("Lower Bound"),
verbatimTextOutput("lower"),

h4("Upper Bound"),
verbatimTextOutput("upper")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
 l <- reactive({
 a <- subset(bounds, num==input$num & succ==input$succ, select=a)
 return(a)
 })
 u <- reactive({
 b <- subset(bounds, num==input$num & succ==input$succ, select=b)
 return(b)
 })
 output$lower <- renderText({
 l
  })
 output$upper <- renderText({
 u
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: as i see you call reactive objects without parenthesis try to add them : 
`output$lower <- renderText({
 l()
  })
 output$upper <- renderText({
 u()
  })`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it will fix everything but i'm sure that you must put brackets to call a reactive object :

```
output$lower <- renderText({
 l()
  })
output$upper <- renderText({
 u()
  })
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately still doesn't seem to be working. Where I am hoping for the answers to be displayed I am getting the error: argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'